# Does Kafka `message.max.bytes` settings on producer side for confluent python client required when compression is enabled?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send a message to kafka where all broker configuration limits to 1MB max message size.
I'm using compression on producer side. This should enable sending larger uncompressed messages.

When I tried sending a 2 MB uncompressed message (100kb compressed), I get error like `message is is large`. I have `'compression.codec' : 'snappy',` settings on producer.

When I set  'message.max.bytes' to more than 2 MB. I was able to send the message and my consumer listening was able to consume it.

The kafka documentation says this size limit is `after compression if compression is enabled`
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_message.max.bytes

If I put this config less than 2MB my message is failing. This tells that this property checks max message size before compression.

I am using confluent python producer. Has any one tested this?